# How can I add a default value to variable in helm chart template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, helm3

How can I add a default value to shutdownDelay to 50 seconds in my template

```
        lifecycle:
        
           
            preStop:
{{ toYaml .Values.lifecycleHooks.preStop | indent 14 }}
            {{- else if gt (int .Values.shutdownDelay) 0 }}
            preStop:
              exec:
                command:
                  - sleep
                  - "{{ int .Values.shutdownDelay }}"
```

I tried few combinations like but nothing is working

Like if shutdownDelay isn't specified in values.yaml use 50 as default value and should appear like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordinarily I'd recommend the [`default`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#default) function

```
... (gt (.Values.shutdownDelay | default 50) 0) ...
```

The problem here is that `0` is an expected value, but it's logical "false" for purposes of `default`, so you won't be able to explicitly specify no delay.  You can't easily tell `0` and `nil` or "absent" apart with simple conditionals like this.

The "big hammer" here is the [`ternary`](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#ternary) function, which acts like the inline `condition ? true_expr : false_expr` conditional expression in C-like languages.  You can use this to select one value if the value is absent and another if it's present.

```
{{- $delay := hasKey .Values "shutdownDelay" | ternary .Values.shutdownDelay 50 }}
{{- if gt $delay 0 }}
...
{{- end }}
```

If you decide to use a more complex expression inside `ternary`, remember that it is an ordinary function and is not "short-circuiting"; the condition and both values are always evaluated even though only one will actually be returned, so your expression will need to pass the various type constraints even if the value is absent.

Comment: Where to place this haskey thing? Can you append it in my code?

Comment: The `if gt $delay 0` line is the same place as the existing `if gt (int .Values.shutdownDelay) 0`; the `$delay := ...` variable assignment can go anywhere before it.

Comment: The code works when I don't specify anything in values.yaml else it is not working.  ` at <gt ($delay) 0>: error calling gt: incompatible types for comparison`

Comment: also how can I convert the value of delay as int like i was doing previously

Comment: I have added the updated code in my answer which does not work when I provide value in values.yaml. can you point out what I am doing wrong

Comment: I'm assuming the value is an integer in the `values.yaml` file, `shutdownDelay: 30`.

Comment: Can you help me with new question. I am stuck at the last point